# What iOS controller is this?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Can anyone tell me if this is a standard iOS controller; I see it often in many different apps. It behaves much like a segmented controller, in that you can select one option and that option "sticks" until you select another. But it also seems a bit different than the out-of-box segmented controller. Is it something else?

[image]

Comment: It's definitely a segmented control, either skinned with iOS 5 methods, or a custom subclass. Maybe even an undocumented style.

Comment: i've seen it in a number of apps, so it can't be too unique

Comment: It is not an undocumented style, because no undocumented style looks like this, an Apple wouldn't have allowed it on to the App Store. Most likely someone has created it and uploaded it to somewhere like GitHub. So try searching for UISegentedControl or UITabBar etc alternatives

Answer (score 0):

I've done a few of those with a row of simple `UIButton` instances